# How to bind DateTime.Now to TextBlock?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

In my Windows 8 app I want to show the current time in a TextBlock element. The time value should update every second. The following code just works fine, but I think it's not exactly the ideal solution. So is there a better way to do this?

```
public class Clock : Common.BindableBase {
    private string _time;
    public string Time {
        get { return _time; }
        set { SetProperty<string>(ref _time, value); }
    }
}

private void startPeriodicTimer() {
    if (PeriodicTimer == null) {
        TimeSpan period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

        PeriodicTimer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer((source) => {

            Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                () => {
                    DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
                    clock.Time = string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss tt}", time);
                    [...]
                });

        }, period);
    }
}
```

In LoadState method:

```
clock = new Clock();
clock.Time = string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss tt}", DateTime.Now);
currentTime.DataContext = clock;
startPeriodicTimer();
```

Comment: You should poll more frequently.  If you do it once per second, you may find that the clock appears to stutter or jump.  Due to clock accuracy and cpu timing issues, "once per second" isn't guaranteed to run at *exactly* 1 second intervals.  It might be a few milliseconds off in either direction.  So set a value of 500 ms and it will be much smoother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinRT has `DispatcherTimer` class. You can use it.

XAML

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:Ticker x:Key="ticker" />
</Page.Resources>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource ticker}, Path=Now}" FontSize="20"/>
```

C#

```
public class Ticker : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Ticker()
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Now"));
    }

    public string Now
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss tt}", DateTime.Now); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a timer.

```
var timer = new Timer { Interval = 1000 };
timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) => NotifyPropertyChanged("Now");
timer.Start();
```

And notify a property each second.

```
public DateTime Now
{
    get { return DateTime.Now; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How I did in my application by using Timer

```
        private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TxtHour.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
        }
private void MainWindow_OnLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
            dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            dispatcherTimer.Start();
            TxtDate.Text = DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString();
        }
```